# check if an input field is selected using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I check if an input field is selected or not, using javascript or jquery
?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which input field checkbox, radio, select ?

Comment: what do you mean by selected? that means the input has focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googleing found a quick solution.

from http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=77983

> There's no built-in way; you have to use the onfocus and onblur events
>   to set some form of flag for each element to be read.
>
> This script automates the process for any number of forms:

Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
/* (c)2006 Stephen Chalmers
 * 
 * Appends a 'hasFocus' flag to all text/textarea form
 * elements.
 *

Insert this script anywhere below the last form in the document.

To read the current focus state of a specified element, use:

if( document.forms.myForm.myElement.hasFocus )
 ...

***/

for(var i=0, df=document.forms, len=df.length; i<len; i++)
 for(j=0, els=df[i].elements; j<els.length; j++)
  if( /^text/.test( els[j].type ) )
  {
   els[j].hasFocus=false;
   els[j].onfocus=function(){this.hasFocus=true;};
   els[j].onblur =function(){this.hasFocus=false;};
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and [selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)